# Performance Implications of Accessing Single MongoDB Document vs Different MongoDB Documents in The Same Collection

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a MongoDB Document that contains within itself a list.

This list gets altered *a lot* and there's no real reason why it couldn't have its own collection and each of the items became a document.

Would there be any performance implications of the former? I've got an inkling that document read/writes are going to be blocked while any given connection tries to read it, but the same wouldn't be true for accessing different documents in the same collection.

Answer (score 0):

I find that these questions are effectively impossible to 'answer' here on Stack Overflow. Not only is there not really a 'right' answer, but it is impossible to get enough context from the question to frame a response that appropriately factors in the items that are most important for you to consider in your specific situation. Nonetheless, here are some thoughts that come to mind that may help point you in the right direction.

Performance is obviously an important consideration here, so it's good to have it in mind as you think through the design. Even within the single realm of performance there are various aspects. For example, would it be acceptable for the source document and the associated secondary documents in another collection to be out of sync? If not, and you had to pursue a route such as using transactions to keep them aligned, then that may be a much bigger performance hit overall and not worth pursuing.

As broad as performance is, it is also just a single consideration here. What about usability? Are you able to succinctly express the type of modifications that you would be doing to the array using MongoDB's query language? What about retrieving the data, would you always pull the information back as a single logical document? If so, then that would imply needing to use `$lookup` very frequently. Even doing so via a view may be cumbersome and could be both a usability as well as performance consideration. Indeed, an [overreliance on `$lookup` can be considered an antipattern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/schema-suggestions/reduce-lookup-operations/).

What does it mean when you say that the list gets "altered" a lot? Are you inserting new information, or updating existing entries? There has been a 16MB size limit for individual documents for a long time in MongoDB, so they generally recommend [avoiding unbounded arrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/schema-suggestions/avoid-unbounded-arrays/). Indeed processing them can be costly in various ways depending on some specific factors.

Also, where does your inkling about concurrency behavior come from? There is a [FAQ on concurrency here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/concurrency/) which helps outline some of the expected behavior for various operations and their locking. Often (with any system) it can be most appropriate to build out an environment that appropriately represents your end state and stress test it directly. That often gives a good general sense for how the approach would work in your situation without having to become an expert in the particulars of how the database (or tool in general) works.

You can see that even in this short response, the "recommendation" fluctuates back and forth. Ultimately this question is about a trade-off which we are not in a good position answer for you. Hopefully this response helps give you some things to think about while doing so.